# rails active record count method not counting rows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

I have to count the number of results returned by the query.I know there is a count method which counts the number of results returned but its not working.
Here is my query:

```
@oi_report = IncidentDetailsReport.find_by_case_id(id).count
```

And I'm getting this exception :

```
undefined method `count' for #<IncidentDetailsReport:0x745def8>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods/count) you can pass conditions via count. So try doing this:

```
IncidentDetailsReport.count(:conditions => "id = "+id)
```

or else can you use `length`?

Comment: This one works.Btw can it skip other extra stuff like where a user might be trying  SQL injection on it?

Comment: I think casting id into integer might help.

Answer (score 2):

You should  use following **query**

```
@oi_report = IncidentDetailsReport.where('case_id=?',id).count
```

Dont use 'find_by_case_id' in this case

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `IncidentDetailsReport.find_by_case_id(id)` returns an object with the type of `IncidentDetailsReport` which has no method `count`, this happens because `find_by_case_id` returns an object not a relation as it adds `LIMIT 1` to the query.

Instead of `find_by_*` you could use `where`, like:

`IncidentDetailsReport.where(:case_id => id).count`

Comment: `where(case_id: id)` is not valid syntax

Comment: as far as I know it is valid in Rails 3.2, but will edit to syntax that works for all rails 3. Thanks !